# Material Dialog Error I am working on listview,

Tags: java, android, dialog, popup

I want to show a Dialog Window inside an adapter but i get this error: Bad window token, you cannot show a dialog before an Activity is created or after it's hidden.  This is MainActivity

```
public class Order extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView OrderList;

    Button Mbyll;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private OrderAdapter adapter;

    public static final String KEY_ORDER_DATA = "oder_data";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_order);
        Mbyll = (Button)findViewById(R.id.mbyll_porosine);
        //OrderList = (ListView.(R.id.list);
       // ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        Mbyll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), com.android.restaurant.activity.Home.class);
                volley_dergo_rregjistrim();
                startActivity(i);

            }


        });
        OrderList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        displayData();



    }



    private void displayData() {

        adapter = new OrderAdapter(getApplication(), DatabaseManager.INSTANCE.getAllCartData() );
        OrderList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }




    public void volley_dergo_rregjistrim(){
        // Tag used to cancel the request

        String url = "My Url";

        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                url, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                try {
                    //Do it with this it will work
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                    boolean trueOrFalse = obj.getBoolean("error");
                    if(trueOrFalse){
                        //String userId = obj.getString("id");

                        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),userId.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }else{
                        JSONObject obj1 = new JSONObject(response);
                        String msg = obj1.getString("message");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),msg.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }



                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error 1 :"+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error2",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }){

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

                OrderRequest order = new OrderRequest();





                order.setOrder_type("2");
                order.setId_reservation(138);




                order.fillRestProductList(DatabaseManager.INSTANCE.getAllCartData());


                Map<String,String> params=new HashMap<String,String>();
                params.put(KEY_ORDER_DATA,new Gson().toJson(order));
                return params;

            }






        };


        VolleyApplication.getInstance().getRequestQueue().add(strReq);

    }

}
```

This is the adapter

```
public class OrderAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<DbProductModel> items;
    private FragmentManager fMan;
    int index;
    public OrderAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<DbProductModel> items ) {
        this.mContext = c;
        this.items = items;

    }



    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return items.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(final int pos, View child, ViewGroup parent) {
        Holder mHolder;
        index = pos;
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
        if (child == null) {
            layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            child = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.card_structure, null);
            mHolder = new Holder();

            mHolder.txt_title = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.card_title);
            mHolder.txt_price = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.card_price);
            mHolder.txt_total_price = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.card_total_price);
            mHolder.txt_total = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.total);
            mHolder.txt_description = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.description_txt);
            mHolder.delete_order = (Button) child.findViewById(R.id.delete);
            mHolder.add = (Button) child.findViewById(R.id.add);
            mHolder.remove = (Button) child.findViewById(R.id.remove);
            mHolder.note = (Button) child.findViewById(R.id.btn_add_note);

            mHolder.pza_image = (ImageView) child.findViewById(R.id.card_imagee);

            child.setTag(mHolder);
        } else {
            mHolder = (Holder) child.getTag();
        }

        mHolder.delete_order.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            //DbProductModel products = id_list.get(index);
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DatabaseManager.INSTANCE.removeProductFromCart(items.get(pos).getId_dish());
                items.remove(pos);
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Delete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        mHolder.add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            //DbProductModel products = id_list.get(index);
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DatabaseManager.INSTANCE.addToCart(items.get(pos));
                items.get(pos).setQuantity(items.get(pos).getQuantity() + 1);
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "added quantity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        mHolder.remove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            //DbProductModel products = id_list.get(index);
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (items.get(pos).getQuantity() > 1) {
                    boolean couldDecrement = DatabaseManager.INSTANCE.decrementQuantityOfProdInCart(items.get(pos).getId_dish());
                    if (couldDecrement) {
                        items.get(pos).setQuantity(items.get(pos).getQuantity() - 1);
                        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "decreased quantity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        });

       mHolder.note.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //NotesDialogFragment.newInstance(items.get(pos).getId_dish()).show(fMan, NotesDialogFragment.class.getSimpleName());
               /// Demo.newInstance(items.get(pos).getId_dish());
                // showInputDialog(v.getContext());
                showInputDialog();
                //showBasicLongContent("","titull");

            }
        });

        mHolder.txt_title.setText(items.get(pos).getName());
        mHolder.txt_price.setText("Cmimi: "+items.get(pos).getPrice());
        mHolder.txt_total_price.setText("Cmimi Total: "+items.get(pos).getPrice_total());
        mHolder.txt_total.setText(""+ items.get(pos).getQuantity());
        mHolder.txt_description.setText(""+ items.get(pos).getDescription());

        Glide.with(mContext)
                .load(My Url"+items.get(pos).getImage())
                .centerCrop()
                .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
                .crossFade()
                .into(mHolder.pza_image);

        return child;
    }

    public class Holder {
       // TextView txt_id;
        TextView txt_title;
        TextView txt_price;
        TextView txt_total_price;
        TextView txt_total;
        TextView txt_description;
        ImageView pza_image;
        Button delete_order;
        Button remove;
        Button add;
        Button note;
    }


  public void showInputDialog() {
        new MaterialDialog.Builder(mContext)
                .title("TEST")
                .content("TEST")
                .inputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT |
                        InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PERSON_NAME |
                        InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_WORDS)
                .inputRange(2, 16)
                .positiveText("TEST")
                .input("TEST", "TEST", false, new MaterialDialog.InputCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onInput(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, CharSequence input) {
                        //showToast("Hello, " + input.toString() + "!");
                    }
                }).show();
    }


}
```

this is my error

```
06-04 10:52:31.844 12468-12468/com.android.restaurant E/libEGL: call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
06-04 10:52:40.252 12468-12468/com.android.restaurant E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: com.android.restaurant, PID: 12468
                                                                        com.afollestad.materialdialogs.MaterialDialog$DialogException: Bad window token, you cannot show a dialog before an Activity is created or after it's hidden.
                                                                            at com.afollestad.materialdialogs.MaterialDialog.show(MaterialDialog.java:1352)
                                                                            at com.afollestad.materialdialogs.MaterialDialog$Builder.show(MaterialDialog.java:1341)
                                                                            at com.android.restaurant.Adapter.OrderAdapter.showBasicLongContent(OrderAdapter.java:193)
                                                                            at com.android.restaurant.Adapter.OrderAdapter$2.onClick(OrderAdapter.java:107)
                                                                            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5197)
                                                                            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20926)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

Comment: can you put your logcat file? also tell us the name of the library you use with material dialog

Comment: compile('com.github.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.5.4@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
this is the library i used

Comment: are you sure you pass context to adapter? can you show where do you call your adapter from?

Comment: yes because i used context on others and tha worked bit with MaterialDialog it does not work :/

Comment: if you are using only "this" keyword try it with "YourActivity.this" instead

Comment: "in builder cannot be applied"

Comment: have you tried getApplicationContext() while sending context instead of "this"?

Comment: yes but it did not worked

Comment: man there is definitely something wrong with your main activity part. share it too so we can check it out. also is this all your adapter class or have your cropted some part from it?

Comment: i showed all code hope it helps you

Comment: adapter = new OrderAdapter(getApplication(), DatabaseManager.INSTANCE.getAllCartData() ); this part is not good man. have you changed it with the words that i told you? Or have you made changes on different parts